# Sending data from a pop-up window to a grid Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using the modular window Angular. In order to change the data in my table. How can I do what would happen to the event to close the data remained unchanged. And at event of a dysmiss the data as well as now were transferred in the table? Here is my code:

Parent

```
modalRef.result.then((data) => {
    this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
});
```

}

Pop-Up

```
saveEntity(): void {
    if (this.RoleId.WorkedYears <= 0) {
        this.toastr.error('Please enter positive number');
    }
    else {
        this.RoleId.WorkedYears = this.RoleId.WorkedYears
        this.activeModal.close();
    }
}

close(): void {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: You can use a service that will hold your data. That way, you can access it from different components by injecting your service with dependency injection.

Comment: making use of shared services as pointed by @AlexBeugnet is the way to go i guess better have a model in service which will be replicated to the grid when you close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use **two way binding** or use **LocalStorage**.